# How to format only time in date fns

Tags: javascript, typescript, date-fns

I want to format 12-hour time to 24-hour time using format() function from date-fns library, however, I got an error.

This is the code:

```
 import {format} from 'date-fns'

 const convertFrom12HourTimeTo24HourTime = (twelveHourTime: TwelveHourTime) => {
    const { hour, minute, meridiem } = twelveHourTime;

    const toFormatTime = new Date(`${hour}:${minute} ${meridiem}`);

    const formattedTime = format(toFormatTime, 'HH:mm');

    console.log(formattedTime);
}
```

Comment: `I got an error` - should we guess what the error is?

Comment: `new Date(`${hour}:${minute} ${meridiem}`);` won't work, ever .. you can't just pass something like `04:56 AM` to `new Date`

Comment: So, how to make that work ?

Comment: `new Date(\`Jan 1 1970 ${hour}:${minute} ${meridiem}\`);` - could possibly work (browser dependant though)

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you want to use `parse` from `date-fns`:

```js
import { parse, format } from 'date-dns'

const convertFrom12HourTimeTo24HourTime = ({ hour, minute, meridiem }: TwelveHourTime) => {
    const toFormatTime = parse(`${hour} ${minute} ${meridiem}`, 'h m a', new Date())

    const formattedTime = format(toFormatTime, 'HH:mm');

    console.log(formattedTime);
}
```

Comment: You misspelled the minute to minutes in line
4 man, perhaps you couldedit it?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it. Does this solution work for you? Apart from the typo ;-)

Comment: of course that's work, thanks for the solutions man

Comment: Happy to hear that :-) You can also express that by selecting this answer as correct...